# results not displaying in foreach

Tags: php, foreach

I have the following code:

```
            $aProfiles = array ();

            $sMainContent = '';
            foreach ($aProfiles as $aProfile) {
                $sMainContent .= $row['date'];
            }
            $ret .= $sMainContent;
            $ret .= '<div class="clear_both"></div>';
            echo $ret;
```

But for the life of me, I can not figure out why it is not displaying any results. I have spent the last 2 days trying different things, but to no avail.

The part that confuses me is the: $aProfiles = array ();. I have tried replacing the array() with an sql query, but that did not work either. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong please.

This code came from a cms for a pagination, and I am trying to use the default pagination with my sql query.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `$aProfiles` array already blank and the `foreach` not working in blank array.

Comment: Change `$row['date']` to `$aProfile['date']`

Comment: @ Roopendra - changed $row to $aProfile and still not working

Comment: @jogesh_pi - i tried changing the $aProfiles = array() to $aProfiles = mysql_query("sql query"); - but not working either

Comment: Opps. you have assigned as blank array . I though in `$aProfiles` you are getting some value. My mistake dude. @jogesh_pi already mention this.

Comment: @user3044341 the logic behind using `foreach` is unclear, why you/developer use this for blank array, you can directly assign the date to `$sMainContent = $row['date'];` without `foreach`.

Answer (score 0):

Array --> $aProfiles = array (); is blank that's why not working.
Please insert some value in this array Example:

```
$aProfiles = array ("value1","value2","value3");
```

Comment: how do i get the array to be filled with data from the database instead of hard-coding values?

Comment: edit your code and show your code with database that you are using?